# ApacheBeam-Java: MS-SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I have an issue with the JdbcIO.read(). When I try to fetch all the records (SELECT * FROM MyTable) it's throwing the following error but works when I select TOP N records(SELECT TOP 100000 * FROM MyTable). The source table has more than 100 million records.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Error :**

"Error message from worker: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)"

**Code**

```
return pipeline.apply("Get [" + objectDetails.getObjectName() + "]",
            JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                    .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                            "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                            String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%1$s:%2$s;DatabaseName=%3$s", databaseDetails.getDatabaseHostName()
                                    , databaseDetails.getPort(), databaseDetails.getDatabaseName()))
                            .withUsername(databaseDetails.getUserName())
                            .withPassword(databaseDetails.getPassword()))
                    .withQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
                    .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                    .withRowMapper(rowMapper));
```

Regards,
Mahesh

Comment: Nothing about `SELECT * FROM MyTable` should return `Subquery returned more than 1 value` for tables. Are you sure your table isn't actually a view? Or a table with computed columns invoking user-defined functions?

Comment: There are computed fields in the table and returning more than one value for a couple of rows...  We will fix it by changing the logic of the computed fields.                                                                                                       Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: Thanks. Do you think JdbcIO should provide a better error here or was this error adequate to detect the error from your side ?